# Cannot Insert Tab spaces ("\t") in J2ME String

Tags: java, java-me, midp, lcdui

I have a String

```
str = "Hello\tWorld";
```

When I print the string in a J2ME application, it results:

`"HelloWorld"` instead of `"Hello<tab space>World"`

When the below sample code is run, the textfield does not display the tab space but it only display "HelloWorld" without tab space.

Sample code:

```
public class MyApp extends MIDlet {

    private Display display;
    private Form frmMain;

    public MyApp() {
        display = Display.getDisplay(this);
        frmMain = new Form("Hello");
    }


    protected void startApp() throws MIDletStateChangeException {
        TextField txt = new TextField("Text", "", 200, TextField.ANY);
        txt.setString("Hello\tWorld");
        frmMain.append(txt);

        display.setCurrent(frmMain);
    }

    protected void pauseApp() {
    }

    protected void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) throws MIDletStateChangeException {
        destroyApp(unconditional);
        notifyDestroyed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some more of the relevant code - like the line where you print it and anything else that might mess it up?

Comment: In theory, the next tab position could just be really close to the end of "Hello". In practice, I think character codes < 32 are just filtered out. What do you want to achieve here with \t -- why don't you use a regular space?

Comment: @StefanHaustein because i have to use \t so as i can format my String. e.g if i have smthing like this. 
`1.    test        test` 
`2.    testtest    test`
so i have to put \t so that they are well align. And i cannot use white space since the length string is not constant. But in j2me in the Formatter class there no such thing like this that allow me to format my string e.g. ("1%s 12%s 12%s", test1, test2, test3) where test1->test3 are string variables

Comment: Really no formats like "%-13s"?

Comment: if the font has a fixed width per character, you could write your own routine that does the alignment by inserting the right amount of spaces. You could test this by checking if "iiii" and "wwww" consume the same space on the screen. this won't be really portable, though... unfortunately, the lcdui classes are quite limited...

Comment: @StefanHaustein I have try that also but they don't consume the same space. That's the problem.

Comment: @JoopEggen No there's no such thing. Only in J2SE, there's a function fotmat() in class Fomatter that allows you to do so.